# Elastic.co APM with gke network policies

Tags: elasticsearch, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-networkpolicy, elastic-cloud

I have gke clusters, and I have elasticsearch deployments on elastic.co. Now on my gke cluster I have network policies for each pod with egress and ingress rules. My issue is that in order to use elastic APM I need to allow egress to my elastic deployment.

Anyone has an idea how to do that? I am thinking either a list of IPs for elastic.co on the gcp instances to be able to whitelist them in my egress rules, or some kind of proxy between my gke cluster and elastic apm.

I know a solution can be to have a local elastic cluster on gcp, but I prefer not to go this way.

Answer (score 1):

About the possibility of using some kind of Proxy between your gke cluster and elastic apm. You can check the following link [1], to see if it can fit your necessities.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#proxyvm

Comment: Thanks Ricard, I did something like that using nginx on a jump-server, just set up as a forwarding proxy. Already finished and it is working great...